# Google Cloud Messaging with Android (How to often to register user)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am very pleased to have gotten the Google Cloud Messaging working. Now, I am wondering how often do I need to register the user to get the registrationID?  Is it possible that the registrationID will ever change?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Service that implements `InstanceIDListenerService#onTokenRefresh()` to know when to request new registration tokens.

```
public class MyInstanceIDService extends InstanceIDListenerService {
  public void onTokenRefresh() {
    refreshAllTokens();
  }

  private void refreshAllTokens() {
    // assuming you have defined TokenList as
    // some generalized store for your tokens
    ArrayList<TokenList> tokenList = TokensList.get();
    InstanceID iid = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
    for(tokenItem : tokenList) {
      tokenItem.token =
        iid.getToken(tokenItem.authorizedEntity,tokenItem.scope,tokenItem.options);
      // send this tokenItem.token to your server
    }
  }
};
```

Then add your Service to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<service android:name=".MyInstanceIDService" android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Source:
https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation#refresh_tokens

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the new Firebase cloud Messaging, you don't have to register anything, it does it automatically for you. But from my experience with GCM, i have always registered every time user manually logins in, for they might be logging in from a different device and therefor you have to register that device in-order for it to receive push notifications.